# Retrieve Document Set Created By value on Client Side

Tags: csom, spservices, document-set

I have a SharePoint Online, 2013 setup.  I want to create some functionality on the Document Set Welcome page using Metadata found in the content type.

I've managed to find the "Status" column, but I cannot figure out how to get the Created By column.  Below is my working code for getting the Current User, as well as the Status.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Content/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Content/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var CurrentUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();
        var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type=\"int\">" + getQString('ID') + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            webURL: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite(),
            listName: "Documents",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
            CAMLQuery: query,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                        //alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                        alert($(this).attr("ows_Status"));
                });
            }
        });
    });
    function getQString(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
        if (results == null)
            return "";
        else
            return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to get the Created By column on the client side?  I would then be using that value to see if they are the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the ows_Author value that was available.

This gives me the name of the Author, which will work in my situation.
I can get the name of the current user:

```
var CurrentUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Title", debug: false});
```

I can parse the name from the ows_Author

```
var CreatedBy = $(this).attr("ows_Author").substr($(this).attr("ows_Author").indexOf("#") + 1);
```

This works for my scenario, but could be problematic if there are two people with the same name.